# Minesweeper problems

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

It looks like the [minesweeper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minesweeper) tag has so many non-puzzle questions.
What shall I do with them?

Also, is [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/minesweeper-puzzle-too-many-twos) question fit for the "puzzling"site?

Comment: l mean the questions asked by @gparyani .

Answer (score 3):

Questions *about* puzzles are completely acceptable for this site. (That was the original purpose of the site, in fact! We only expanded to allow questions that were themselves puzzles later on.) I don't see any particularly problematic questions in the tag, except maybe the more "brute-force search" ones.

The question you shared seems fine to me.

Comment: Are the questions asked by @gparyani okay? They all have the "minesweeper" tags, but they aren't puzzles, they're video games. They should go to Arqade.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat They're questions about puzzles (that happen to be in a video game). I see no problem with them. It may or may not also be true that they are acceptable on Arqade -- but even if they are, that doesn't mean they're off-topic here. Many questions fit on multiple SE sites, and many fit on none at all.